# I am trying to parse date but I got timezone exception

Tags: android, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

Here is my date String "Thu Feb 25 12:58:28 MST 2016" and I parse using this formate "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy".

But I am getting date parsing error.

What should I do?

I am parsing date string using following function

```
public static String getDate(String targrtDate) {
    String dateStr = targrtDate;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(date);

    if (date == null) {
        return "";
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String formatedTime = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Log.i("formatedDate", "" + formatedDate + " " + formatedTime);

    return formatedDate;
}
```

Comment: The code you are using working fine.. Just import Date class from  java.util.Date. If you importing date class from import java.sql.Date then you will get Exception.
Just Import Date class from java.sql.Date.

Comment: Yes, I import same class which you told me but If I use Thu Feb 25 12:58:28 GMT 2016 then working fine but when I used MST as a timezone it gives parsing error.

Comment: What is the solution of MST timezone?

Comment: I have just change your code 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
it is working fine 
I have tested date "Thu Feb 25 12:58:28 MST 2016"
once check this

Comment: For safety, you should use `new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);` because your pattern is locale-sensitive, and your default locale might not be English.

Comment: I have resolved my issue with the help of  `new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);` Thank you @MenoHochschild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue of date parsing.

If someone use MST timezone and if it gives an parsing error then please add second parameter of SimpleDateFormat() as

`new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);`

So my final code will be

```
public static String getDate(String targrtDate) {
    String dateStr = targrtDate;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(date);

    if (date == null) {
        return "";
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String formatedTime = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Log.i("formatedDate", "" + formatedDate + " " + formatedTime);

    return formatedDate;
}
```

Special thanks to @MenoHochschild

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "Thu Feb 25 12:58:28 MST 2016" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US ) 
)
```

> 2016-02-25T12:58:28-07:00[America/Denver]

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes. For Android, see last bullets below.

```
String input =  "Thu Feb 25 12:58:28 MST 2016" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this code run live at IdeOne.com. (But note that the JVM on that site is hard-wired to `Locale.US`, and any other is ignored.)

> zdt.toString(): 2016-02-25T12:58:28-07:00[America/Denver]

Your input string is in a terrible format. If possible, change to using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The standard formats are practical, easy to parse by machine and easy to read by humans across cultures. Conveniently, these formats are used by default in the java.time classes when parsing/generating strings.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `MST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zEdmonton = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZoneId zDenver = ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) ;
ZoneId zMazatlan = ZoneId.of( "America/Mazatlan" ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).